# Paypal IPN getting delayed by hours

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using paypal adaptive payments to make transaction via paypal. Although few of transactions are taking more than 6 hours too receive IPN.

I've gone through forum posts and their documentation, I came through  - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

"Because IPN is not a real-time service, your checkout flow should not wait for the IPN message before it is allowed to complete. If the checkout flow is dependent on receiving an IPN message, processing can be delayed by system load or other reasons. You should configure your checkout flow to handle a possible delay."

The callback is taking more than 6 hours is way too much. any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you checked your IPN history and your server logs to ensure there isn't an error happening within your IPN script causing a bad response to go back to PayPal?  If your IPN URL has lots of errors they will put you on a slow queue so you don't take up so many resources.

Comment: yeh, I've checked both IPN history and server logs and they looks ok. it returns status code 200.

Comment: I guess they could just be delayed, but that's pretty rare for it to be that long.  I haven't noticed such delays with my IPNs lately.

Comment: agreed, this happens with 2 out 10 transactions.

Comment: There is no SLA. I've seen them delayed by days. Ask PayPal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to PayPal, and is not about computer programming.

Answer (score 2):

I've built several custom carts. On average, I see the PayPal IPN come back within 2 minutes at the longest, and usually recurring payments take longer than single payments because they send two IPN messages, not just one, on the initial setup. I usually take the 'custom' property and put a unique identifier that I have permanently cookied. So, even though I may see an initial IPN come in on a recurring payment, I wait for the one that says that `txn_type` is `subscr_payment` and also that `payment_status` is `Completed`. You can't really trust a subscription payment as being paid unless you see that second message. And if it's a single payment, then I look for `txn_type` to be `web_accept` and `payment_status` to `Completed`.

The way I handle things is to redirect the customer to PayPal to purchase using the form button technique. The customer pays and then gets redirected (thanks to the form hidden vars I created initially) back to my own custom cart URL that I specify. I call that URL the payment-confirmation script. I display a message with a progress bar to please wait while their payment is being confirmed with PayPal. I hold them there 10 seconds and then redirect to the receipt. It is on the receipt where I check the database to see if my IPN script has already processed this order. If not, then I redirect them back to the payment-confirmation script again for another 10 second progress bar delay. My receipt uses a session cookie to ensure I never send them into a loop more than one time to the payment-confirmation script. So, the customer waits another 10 seconds and then comes back to the receipt page, where I test again, reading my permanent cookie on the 'custom' property that I saved, versus the 'custom' property that comes in from the IPN that I use as the order key in the database. Usually within the first or second 10 second delay, the IPN has come in and I can proceed. However, if the IPN has still not come in, then I redirect to a friendly error message saying that their payment cannot be confirmed and to call our call center to remedy the issue. Our call center techs then see the delay problem in PayPal, back the other transaction out, and sell to the customer over the phone manually, instead.